# App tested extensively, also approved by apple, but crashes for all users once in App Store

Tags: ios, crash, unity-game-engine, app-store

So we have existing app in app store, made second update for it.
Tested extensively with internal dev team, (with both debug and release, and test flight builds) then test team 1, followed by a second test team (that double checks the first test team)
Submitted to apple, and it passed, and went live to app store...
now for everyone 100% of users that downloads it, it crashes.  How can this be ?
Had to pull it from app store.

Built with latest unity 4.3, with almost latest xcode, 5.0 on Mac

Here is crash log (note I removed the bundle id and app names manually, they are correct)
There are 2 errors mentioned and a strange word I wouldn't expect to see 'sandbox'
Q. why does it say 'sandbox' on line 1??

any thoughts appreciated, thanks in advance

```
Mar 14 10:08:46 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 kernel[0] : launchd[245] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/9810A9BD-C625-41A2-95A1-034CFF74E561 (sandbox)
Mar 14 10:08:46 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 networkd[81] : Analytics Engine: double ON for app: com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx
Mar 14 10:08:46 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 appNameHere[245] : -> registered mono modules 0x1aaa550
Mar 14 10:08:46 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 backboardd[31] : HID: The 'Passive' connection 'appNameHere' access to protected services is denied.
Mar 14 10:08:46 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 appNameHere[245] : searching for iCloud document directory and found this: (null)
Mar 14 10:08:47 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 awdd[247] : CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
Mar 14 10:08:47 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 backboardd[31] : CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
Mar 14 10:08:47 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 backboardd[31] : CoreAnimation: timed out fence 2df07
Mar 14 10:08:47 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 SpringBoard[16] : CoreAnimation: failed to receive fence reply: 10004003
Mar 14 10:08:48 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 ReportCrash[248] : ReportCrash acting against PID 245
Mar 14 10:08:49 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 ReportCrash[248] : Formulating crash report for process appNameHere[245]
Mar 14 10:08:49 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx[0x5c][245]) : (UIKitApplication:com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx[0x5c]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Mar 14 10:08:49 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 backboardd[31] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx[0x5c]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Mar 14 10:08:49 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 ReportCrash[248] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/appNameHere_2014-03-14-100848_QAQ-iPhone5S-01.ips using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Mar 14 10:08:49 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 mc_mobile_tunnel[244] : (Note ) MC: mc_mobile_tunnel shutting down.
Mar 14 10:09:35 QAQ-iPhone5S-01 backboardd[31] : ALS: SetDisplayFactor: factor=0.0500
```

Comment: These are not crash logs but just log data from the console. Without a proper (symbolicated) crash report we even provided educated guesses.

Comment: +1. @CthulhuJon, do you have a symbolicated crash report you could post?

Comment: The sandbox is Apple's way of segmenting data between all the apps on an iOS device: Every app only has access to whatever data is in its sandbox. From looking at the 4th and 5th lines of what you've pasted in above, it looks like your app tried to access the iCloud document directory but was denied access by the sandbox. You might want to check and make sure you've requested the correct entitlements for your app.

Comment: If your app connects to anything (like a database you have hosted somewhere); have you made 100% certain that the live environment is working and reachable from outside any corporate networks you might be behind?

Comment: @CthulhuJon I guess you sorted this out by now - it would be nice to know what happened, for anyone else that finds this thread.

Answer (score -1):

While testing have you tried to test the scenario of updating the app. ie., installing the old app, using it normally, covering all major functions of the app and then updating the app using this ipa.